# Grouping of elements done in css that changes the number of elements grouped based on breakpoint

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a number of elements, that I want to group by breakpoint, for example:

- large: 4
- medium: 3
- small: 2

Between each group of rows, there is space at top(see blue border).

At this moment I do the splitting in backend, but in backend I don't know the 
breakpoint, need to have multiple pr-emade breakpoints, harder to change.
I have 2 pre-made groups now.

It is possible to do it(grouping) in css instead of backend and  keeping the space between group rows ?

```css
.group {
    align-items: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.group:first-child { margin: 0; }
.group:last-child { margin-bottom: 50px; }

.group .item { 
  border: 1px solid red;

}

.group-4 .item { 
  width:100%/4;
}
```

```html
<div class="group group-4 group-3-md group-2-sm">
  <div class="item">
     <a class="button" href="components">Element1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <a class="button" href="components">Element2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <a class="button" href="components">Element3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <a class="button" href="components">Element4</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="group group-4 group-3-md group-2-sm">
  <div class="item">
     <a class="button" href="components">Element1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <a class="button" href="components">Element2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <a class="button" href="components">Element3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <a class="button" href="components">Element4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to have 20px between lines, why should I remove it ?, I want to change how many elements enter in a row per breakpoint, keeping the space between rows

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Maybe that's why nobody has responded. Try clarifying or simplifying the question.